# Seeing fuzzy colors and blurry fonts on Dell

Tags: graphics-card, dell-inspiron, intel-graphics

I have a Dell Inspiron 17R-5737 laptop.

**Question**

- How can I determine whether changing my graphics card will fix the problem?

**Problem** 
I'm seeing fuzzy colors and blurry fonts on the laptop screen. However, when I connect the laptop to the TV with HDMI I can see the laptop screen on the TV perfectly fine.

**What I've done**
I've ran the Laptop LCD Built-In Self Test and it seemed ok because I saw the colors that the laptop screen displayed.

**Detailed information**
Here is the information from system device and running dxdialog

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: "*What graphics card should I buy for this laptop and from where?*" makes this off topic. You may want to remove that part of the question to avoid closure.

Comment: Hmm. "blurry fonts on the laptop screen" - no evidence of that on the screen shots.

Comment: It doesn't show on the screenshots. I believe for the same reasons that the screen looks fine when connected to an external monitor

Comment: @DavidPostill yes, I found that weird as well. I believe that is for the same reason as no evidence of blurry screen when the laptop is connected to an external monitor.

Comment: Have you tried calibrating ClearType on  your laptop monitor? What is the DPI setting on your monitor?

Comment: Yes, I've went through the ClearType screen and it hasn't had an impact. I don't know what the DPI setting is. I could not find it in control panel -> Display